# Display different sidebar content based on page url - October CMS

Tags: php, symfony, twig, octobercms

I have 2 pages index.htm and links.htm and a partial sidebar.htm.

I'm trying to get my sidebar to display different content based on whether index.htm or links.htm is active.

Reading through the documentation it looks as if you can do this with the param.tab but I can't get it to work and not sure if this is the best way to accomplish this seeing as it's a partial.

sidebar.htm

```
description = "sidebar"
url = "/sidebar/:{% this.page.url %}"
==
{% if this.param.tab == 'links' %}
Display this if page = links
{% elseif this.param.tab == 'index' %}
Display this is page = index
{% endif %}
```

In blade I used - @elseif(isset($guidesslugs) && $guidesslugs->guidesslug == 'area-guide') but I'm not sure how to accomplish the same thing using twig or whether it's possible to used the param.tab on a partial?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**There's multiple ways to do it.**

---

First of all, partials may not have the `url` parameter into config section.

> The Configuration section is optional for partials and can contain the
>   optional `description` parameter which is displayed in the back-end user
>   interface.

[Partials - Introduction](http://octobercms.com/docs/cms/partials#introduction)

---

You could use `param` if the sidebar has different content based on the same page. Example:

**pages/home.htm**

```
url = "/home/:type"
==
{% partial 'sidebar' type=this.param.type %}
```

**partials/sidebar.htm**

```
{% if type == 'foo' %}
  {# foo type #}
{% elseif type == 'bar' %}
  {# bar type #}
{% else %}
  {# anything... #}
{% endif %}
```

When including partials you can pass variables, in this case, we injected `type` as `this.param.type` value. You could also access `this.param` (global) variable inside partial:

**partials/sidebar.htm**

```
{% if this.param.type == 'foo' %}
  {# foo type #}
{% endif %}
```

If I understand your question, you have two different pages where each has his own distinct url so doesn't seems like a case for `param` property.

---

**Use `this.page` variable.**

You're able to access the page `url` defined into page configuration section by using:

```
{{ this.page.url }}
```

*This property seems like hidden from [docs](http://octobercms.com/docs/markup/this-page).*

So considering your structure:

**pages/home**

```
url = "/home"
layout = "default"
==
{% partial 'sidebar' %}
```

**pages/links**

```
url = "/links"
layout = "default"
==
{% partial 'sidebar' %}
```

**partials/sidebar**

```
{% if this.page.url == '/home' %}
  {# home page #}
{% elseif this.page.url == '/links' %}
  {# links page #}
{% else %}
  {# other pages #}
{% endif %}
```

As I said, there's so many ways to do this by defining variables, passing parameters to partial and others.

Comment: thank you, using {% if this.page.url == '/home' %} seems to work so I'll try this going forward